# How to render new if transaction block fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe to process payments. The reason why I am using a transaction block is to ensure that the following succeed or none at all:

- Payment record is written to the db
- Stripe payment is executed

The one thing I can't get to work is the `rescue` block. I am deliberately giving Stripe an invalid credit card to make the transaction fail. However, when it fails, it doesn't `render :new`

```
  def create
    manager = current_session.manager
    plan = Plan.find params[:plan_id]

    Payment.transaction do
      Payment.create(
        plan_id: params[:plan_id],
        management_id: current_session.management.id
      )

      begin
        stripe_customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(manager.payment_provider_customer_id) if manager.try(:payment_provider_customer_id).present?

        if stripe_customer.present?
          # do something here
        else
          stripe_customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
            email: manager.email,
            metadata: {
              manager_id: manager.id
            }
          )
          stripe_customer.cards.create(card: 'zzzzzzzzzzzz')
          stripe_customer.subscriptions.create(plan: plan.payment_provider_plan_id)
        end
      rescue => error
        # If any of the Stripe requests fail, then we must also rollback the payment transaction
        puts "Error: #{error}"
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
        render :new
      else
        redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Thank you. Your payment is being processed.'
      end
    end
  end
```

The error I get is:

```
Missing template dashboard/payments/create, dashboard/application/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee, :slim]}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're raising the ActiveRecord::Rollback exception and then trying to render `:new`. The code after the exception raise will never execute. I would suggest you to separate the method that manages the transaction, like this:

```
def create
  your_processing_transaction_method
  redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Thank you. Your payment is being processed.'
rescue ActiveRecord::Rollback
  render :new and return
end

private

def your_processing_transaction_method
  manager = current_session.manager
  plan    = Plan.find params[:plan_id]

  Payment.transaction do
    Payment.create(
      plan_id: params[:plan_id],
      management_id: current_session.management.id
    )

    begin
      stripe_customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(manager.payment_provider_customer_id) if  manager.try(:payment_provider_customer_id).present?

      if stripe_customer.present?
        # do something here
      else
        stripe_customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
          email: manager.email,
          metadata: {
            manager_id: manager.id
          }
        )
        stripe_customer.cards.create(card: 'zzzzzzzzzzzz')
        stripe_customer.subscriptions.create(plan: plan.payment_provider_plan_id)
      end
    rescue => error
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
    end
  end
end
```

Keep in mind that this is obviously not the best design decision (that is, handling all this kind of transaction processing and business code in the controller). Controllers should only have the responsibility of receiving a request, hand it to the domain model and return a response based on the domain's response.

It will be a better approach to extract this private method to a service class, but I think it could help with the transaction/rendering issue.

Comment: Still the same, `Template is missing` error. It seems it is still trying to render the create template

Comment: Did your `puts` statement print out ?

Comment: Ohh, my mistake. The problem is because you're raising and Exception and then trying to render the `:new` action. You have to extract this begin/rescue block into another method and in the controller you wrap this method in another begin/rescue block. That way, when the ActiveRecord::Rollback exception is caught, you render `:new` and return. Do you want me to update the answer ? It will be quite a major change on the code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are calling

```
render :new
```

you need

```
render :new and return
```

The code is continuing on after the render due to no return and then implicitly rendering the create template